# Efficient datastructure for pooling integers

Tags: algorithm, optimization, data-structures

I'm looking for a data structure to help me manage a pool of integers.  It's a pool in that I remove integers from the pool for a short while then put them back with the expectation that they will be used again.  It has some other odd constraints however, so a regular pool doesn't work well.

Hard requirements:

- constant time access to what the largest in use integer is.
- the sparseness of the integers needs to be bounded (even if only in principal).
  I want the integers to be close to each other so I can quickly iterate over them with minimal unused integers in the range.

Use these if they help with selecting a data structure, otherwise ignore them:

- Integers in the pool are 0 based and contiguous.
- The pool can be constant sized.
- Integers from the pool are only used for short periods with a high churn rate.

I have a working solution but it feels inelegant.
*My (sub-optimal) Solution*

Constant sized pool.
Put all available integers into a sorted set (free_set).
When a new integer is requested retrieve the smallest from the free_set.
Put all in-use integers into another sorted set (used_set).
When the largest is requested, retrieve the largest from the used_set.

There are a few optimization that may help with my particular solution (priority queue, memoization, etc).  But my whole approach seems wasteful.

I'm hoping there some esoteric data structure that fits my problem perfectly.  Or at least a better pooling algorithm.

Comment: Sorry, what's wrong with a heap + hashset (or bloom filter, or nothing, if you don't need to keep track of old integers), where you just fill in a new integer when you pop out an old one (or whenever you want to fill with new integers)?

Comment: `used_set` needs to be more than a set (at least a sorted set), else retrieving the largest integer won't be an O(1) operation. Also, why bother pre-populating `free_set`? When you need a new integer and the free pool is empty, just construct a new one.

Comment: `the sparseness of the integers needs to be bounded (even if only in principal).` - Could you elaborate on this requirement?

Comment: @TedHopp, yeah, same goes for free_set.  I'll update, but I don't have a lot of faith that two sorted sets is the way to go.

Comment: Does "0 based and contiguous" mean you're always storing all the integers from 0 to N? If so, is there any reason to store anything except N since you can generate the entire rest of the set from N? If not, what does it mean?

Comment: @amit, what I mean is that similar to skips lists look up of `n*lg(n)`.  In theory its worst case is `n`, but in practice is `n*lg(n)`.  It can't be proved that the average case is `n*lg(n)`.  In my case I'd like the integers to be tightly packed close to 0, but I don't require a formal proof or upper bounds on the sparseness.

Comment: @JerryCoffin,  What I'm really doing a managing an array of objects.  At any moment only a few are active.  The integer pool keeps track of which indices are used and which aren't.  So yes the pool only holds the integers from 0 to N.  My application asks for a free (unused) index, then gives it back to the pool when the object is no longer in use.

Comment: @deft_code: So that was really describing your current implementation, not the problem itself. In the problem itself, you simply have a sparse set of values, and what to be able to get the largest (and possibly the smallest?) in constant time? You say you have a high churn rate, so presumably you also care about insertion and deletion speed? When you "churn" are you removing all the current contents, and putting in new, or do you insert and delete arbitrary elements, and need to know the largest at any time?

Comment: @JerryCoffin, Yes I have a sparse set of values and I want to be able to get largest and smallest (or 0) in constant time.  By churn I mean that  new elements are arbitrarily inserted/delete.  Insertion and deletion speed should be good but in my case are completely dominated by iteration over the sparse set.  I generally iterate at least as often as I insert/delete.  So my iteration time is `N+sparseness` where my insert/delete are `lg(n)`.  So long as insert and delete are less than `O(N)` I'll be fine.

Comment: @deft_code: From the sound of that, a simple tree-based set should be reasonable. Finding the largest isn't constant complexity, but is logarithmic -- and so are insertion and deletion. Unless your set is *tremendously* huge, the difference between logarithmic and constant rarely means much (e.g., logarithmic comes to ~10 operations for a thousand elements, ~20 operations for a million elements, and ~30 for a billion elements).

Comment: You can get largest and smallest elements of most trees in constant time.  Certainly stl's structures support this with begin() and end().

Answer (score 0):

pseudo class:

```
class IntegerPool {

  int size = 0;
  Set<int> free_set = new Set<int>();

  public int Acquire() {
    if(!free_set.IsEmpty()) {
      return free_set.RemoveSmallest();
    } else {
      return size++;
    }
  }

  public void Release(int i) {
    if(i == size - 1) {
      size--;
    } else {
      free_set.Add(i);
    }
  }

  public int GetLargestUsedInteger() {
    return size;
  }
}
```

**Edit**

`RemoveSmallest` isn't useful as all. `RemoveWhatever` is good enough. So `Set<int>` can be replaced by `LinkedList<int>` as a faster alternative (or even `Stack<int>`).

Comment: This solution fails when you take (1,2,3), and return 2,3 [in this order] and then ask for largest - it will return 2, while the answer is 1. I believe one can overcome this issue, but I guess it will require a second set, which will make the solution decay into the OP's proposed solution.

Comment: You can overcome it when decreasing size [in release()]: start pulling the largest element from free_set, and decrease `size` for each element you pull, until you find a "gap" between size and the highest element. However, it will increase latency of `release()`, but I suspect it will not damage amortized time complexity. It requires a `SortedSet` and not a stack/list as the edit suggests.

Comment: Maybe a vector where each slot is either "in_use" or "free". Free slots contain indices to the previous and next free slots. When you acquire an int, it's taken from the free list. If empty, a slot is added to the vector. When you release, said slot is added to the free list, then free slots at the end of the vector are removed.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a balanced binary search tree?  You can store a pointer/iterator to the min element and access it for free, and updating it after an insert/delete is an O(1) operation.  If you use a self balancing tree, insert/delete is O(log(n)).  To elaborate:

> **insert** : Just compare new element to previous min; if it is better make the iterator point to the new min.
>
> **delete** : If min was deleted, then before removing find the successor (which you can do by just walking the iterator forward 1 step), and then take that guy to be the new min.

While it is theoretically possible to do slightly better using some kind of sophisticated uber-heap data structure (ie Fibonacci heaps), in practice I don't think you would want to deal with implementing something like that just to save a small log factor.  Also, as a bonus you get fast in-order traversal for free -- not to mention that most programming languages these days^ come with fast implementations of self-balancing binary search trees out of the box (like red-black trees/avl etc.).

^ with the exception of javascript :P

*EDIT: Thought of an even better answer.*

Comment: How is what you're suggesting different than my current solution?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are doing to maintain the sorted sets?  Also, if you don't keep track of the min/max explicitly it would cost O(log(n)) to get the item rather than be a constant time operation.  At any rate, you could make an easy argument that you can't do much better than this, since you could reduce your problem to sorting.  (Just insert a bunch of elements into one of your arrays, then call take min/delete enough times ala heap sort.)